# Set a fixed width and height for the "CropRect" in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I want to crop the image after capture or select an image from library. How to change the displayable frame size of UIImagePickerController crop area.

I attached an image to get an idea about my question
When i capture or select image i get the red square frame. Actually what i want to do is resize the red square frame size to green square.

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAyez.png)

```
func openGallary()
{
    picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    picker!.allowsEditing = true;
    picker!.delegate = self;
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
    {
        self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: picker!)
        popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(editPP.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: post what you have tried ?

Comment: i attached an image to make it easy.

Comment: you should add code what you have tried as well as the problem you are facing .

Comment: ok i added that part

Comment: now you got an upvote an also answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding it is not possible to set rect for `UIImagePickerController`  edit mode. You can capture unedited image and crop it your self or you can use  [TOCropViewController](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController)
its nice.
Picker only crops 320X320.